# The column status returned was The value violated the schema's constraint for the column

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, ssis, sqldatatypes

I have a SQL Server table column with length as nvarchar(2000). Wanted to transfer the data to Excel file 2007  using SSIS.

**What i did**

[image]

Source column Data type is Nvarchar(2000) which is DT_NTEXT on SSIS.
on Excel the column Datatype is Nvarchar(255)

Below blue color circled Columns are giving me troubles.

**Source MetaData**

[image]

What can we do to take the whole source column data into one cell in the excel column?

The error I'm getting an error

**ERROR**

[Excel Destination [8]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x00040EDA.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "The field is too small to accept the amount of data you attempted to add. Try inserting or pasting less data.".

> [Excel Destination [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZCRB.png)] Error: There was an error with Excel Destination.Inputs[Excel Destination Input].ColumnsComment] on Excel Destination.Inputs[Excel Destination Input]. The column status returned was: "The value violated the schema's constraint for the column
>
> [Excel Destination [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gZCRB.png)] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "Excel Destination.Inputs[Excel Destination Input]" failed because error code 0xC0209076 occurred, and the error row disposition on "Excel Destination.Inputs[Excel Destination Input]" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.

How can i overcome this problem.

Comment: By ensuring that the values don't violate the constraints on the column. You don't tell us what those constraints are, or what the value failing it is, so there's little further we can really offer at this point.

Comment: The length of the Source column is more than 1000 char - Nvarchar type.  Excel is accepting only 255 char. Why Excel is not accepting more than 255 char on a cell.

Comment: The metadata for a column declared as nvarchar(2000) or even nvarchar(4000) would not result in a column being identified as DT_NTEXT. You've done something to get your metadata out of whack. Metadata ought to look like this --> https://i.stack.imgur.com/muepg.png  Rename the `ColumnsComment` column in the source query to X and then after everything goes red b/c of the change, switch it back to ColumnsComment. That should force a re-initialization of the metadata for the pipeline.

Comment: I followed your idea @billinkc - but still, it did not work.

Comment: The circled columns are defined as nvarchar(max). Your problem statement indicated that nvarchar(2000) columns were the culprits. You cannot stuff an large object type into a cell in Excel. Your only choice is to truncate it at 4000 characters (or multiple 4k columns if that is the business requirement